# Modal Bootstrap in ASP web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem on my Bootstrap Modal and Button ASP. This my modal window:

[image].

There is `FileUpload` with style

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=file]').bootstrapFileInput();
        $('.file-inputs').bootstrapFileInput();
    });
</script>
```

When I clicking button `Save`:

```
<asp:Button Text="Save" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="btn btn-success"
            OnClick="Unnamed_Click" data-dismiss="modal"  runat="server" />
```

and again calling my modal `Launch demo modal`, my style `FileUpload` reset:

[image].

Comment: when save button is clicked , what happens ? do the file saves any where ?

Comment: asp:fileupload control does not retain its value after post back , so if you want this to be show after post back , you have to it in any temporary location and then set the selected file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "123", "GoodsCehck();", true);
    }

   <script>
        GoodsCehck(){
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('input[type=file]').bootstrapFileInput();
                $('.file-inputs').bootstrapFileInput();
          });
          }
   </script>
```